# How do I change a promotion strategy in one of my Jenkins X environments?

Tags: jenkins-x

I've used the "jx create spring -d web -d actuator" command to create a simple Spring java application but I can't figure out how I'd change the promotion strategy from Auto to Manual. Can't see how it's being set in the environment configuration.

https://jenkins-x.io/about/features/#promotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `jx edit env` to edit your `Environment` configurations. Or you can use `kubectl edit env staging` if you want and edit the custom resource directly.

See: https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_edit_environment/

Comment: would it be something like `jx edit env -n staging --promotion automatic` ??

Comment: Thanks James. Running the command `jx edit env -b -n staging -p Manual` works, but I'm wondering how this applied to the github environment repo. Just keen to do it the 'GitOps' way. Loving JX BTW! ;-)

Comment: we're just finishing up using GitOps to manage the installation of Jenkins X itself; you can try it out creating a cluster `jx create cluster gke --ng` and then a git repository is created for the `dev` environment so we can manage upgrading/configuring Jenkins X in the same GitOps style. In this case you can modify the environment configurations in the `env/templates/staging-env.yaml` etc